# Extracting a specific child element from a parent in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My goal is to extract the element '$37.91'.

However, since its class (highlighted yellow) is repeated somewhere else, I couldn't obtain this specific element every time. (Sometimes I obtain other values)

How do I obtain the element through something like: //div id='snsPrice' & span class='a-size-large a-color-price'. To ensure precision.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#snsPrice > .snsPriceBlock > .a-color-price')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="snsPrice"]/div/span[@class="a-size-large a-color-price"]')
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do the same thing using find_element_by_xpath?

In addition, why is there a hashtag before "snsPrice"?

Comment: @Nick123 I updated the answer. You might have to tweak it as I cannot test it.

Comment: An element’s id in XPATH is defined using: “[@id='example']” and in CSS using: “#”

Comment: I tried your xpath code to scrap for the element, seems that I could only get a "NoSuchElementException" error. 

Though the cssselector code works.

This is the webpage:
https://www.amazon.com/Rebellion-Explosive-Workout-Energy-System/dp/B00YTZMY4C/ref=sr_1_6_a_it?ie=UTF8&qid=1511547013&sr=8-6&keywords=rebellion

Comment: @Nick123 Updated the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath
String cost=driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[contains(@class,'total-price-value')]).getText();